# How to save data to database using retrieved ID from datagridview?

Tags: c#, mysql, xampp

I wanted to insert some data to the mysql database using that ID that I have retrieved from datagridview. i am new in programming. can someone please help me? thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you need to download and intall

```
MySQL ADO.Net connector
```

it's the official ado.net connector for C# applications. once you intall that you can use ado.net standered data access methods to save data.

### basic steps

- First create a connection to the my sql data base.
- Then create a command object contains the insert command.
- then provide the object that contain the so called ID and finalize the command object
- then Execute the command against the database.

### Sample code

This is the class variables that will be used later

```
private MySqlConnection connection; // this MySqlConnection class comes with the connector
private string server;
private string database;
private string uid;
private string password;
```

This will Initialize method will configure the connection with the configuration data

```
private void Initialize()
{
    server = "localhost";
    database = "connectcsharptomysql";
    uid = "username";
    password = "password";
    string connectionString;
    connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + 
    database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

    connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
}
```

this method will open a connection to the database . you should write a C Lose method as well .because it's best practice to always close the connection after you used it

```
private bool OpenConnection()
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        return true;
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        //When handling errors, you can your application's response based 
        //on the error number.
        //The two most common error numbers when connecting are as follows:
        //0: Cannot connect to server.
        //1045: Invalid user name and/or password.
        switch (ex.Number)
        {
            case 0:
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator");
                break;

            case 1045:
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This will insert a record to database . query will contains the T-SQL query that runs against the database

```
public void Insert()
{
    string query = "INSERT INTO tableinfo (name, age) VALUES('John Smith', '33')";

    //open connection
    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        //create command and assign the query and connection from the constructor
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

        //Execute command
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //close connection
        this.CloseConnection();
    }
}
```

Hope this will help